# synchronized block with static reference/object in multi-threading environment

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, static, synchronization

Though this question might be asked several time on SO(mostly in form of `this` vs `Bar.clas`s in Synchronized block), but i am not clear about the Synchronization on Static reference/object of a class(3rd example) of this question. Please have a look on below Java examples:

1. **Example#1** - `synchronized` block with `this` keyword

   public class Bar implements Runnable {

   ```
   @Override
   public void run() {
       objectLock();
   }

   public void objectLock() {

       synchronized(this) {
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
           System.out.println("synchronized block " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
           System.out.println("synchronized block " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " end");
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Bar b1 = new Bar();
       Thread t1 = new Thread(b1);
       Thread t2 = new Thread(b1);
       Thread t3 = new Thread(b1);

       Bar b2 = new Bar();
       Thread t4 = new Thread(b2);
       Thread t5 = new Thread(b2);
       Thread t6 = new Thread(b2);

       t1.setName("t1");
       t2.setName("t2");
       t3.setName("t3");
       t4.setName("t4");
       t5.setName("t5");
       t6.setName("t6");


       t1.start();
       t2.start();
       t3.start();

       t4.start();
       t5.start();
       t6.start();

   }
   ```

   }

**Result** :  While any thread From `t1,t2,t3` acquire lock through synchronized block(say `t1` acquire), then `t2` and `t3` would be in **blocked** state, but at the same time other threads `t4`,`t5` and `t6` are allowed to perform **concurrently**.

2. **Example#2** - `synchronized` block with `Bar.class`

   public class Bar implements Runnable {

   ```
       @Override
       public void run() {
           objectLock();
       }

       public void objectLock() {

           synchronized(Bar.class) {
               System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
               System.out.println("synchronized block " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
               System.out.println("synchronized block " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " end");
           }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Bar b1 = new Bar();
           Thread t1 = new Thread(b1);
           Thread t2 = new Thread(b1);
           Thread t3 = new Thread(b1);

           Bar b2 = new Bar();
           Thread t4 = new Thread(b2);
           Thread t5 = new Thread(b2);
           Thread t6 = new Thread(b2);

           t1.setName("t1");
           t2.setName("t2");
           t3.setName("t3");
           t4.setName("t4");
           t5.setName("t5");
           t6.setName("t6");


           t1.start();
           t2.start();
           t3.start();

           t4.start();
           t5.start();
           t6.start();

       }
   }
   ```

**Result** :  Only one thread of any instance of `Bar` class, will acquire lock(say `t1` acquire lock) and all other thread(`t2,t3...t6`) will be blocked till `t1` releases the lock.

3. **Example#3** - `synchronized` block with `static` **Reference**/**Object**

public class Bar implements Runnable {

```
private static  Integer NUM=new Integer(5);

@Override
public void run() {
    objectLock();
}

public void objectLock() {

    synchronized(NUM) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(NUM++);
        System.out.println("synchronized block " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("synchronized block " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " end");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bar b1 = new Bar();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(b1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(b1);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(b1);

    Bar b2 = new Bar();
    Thread t4 = new Thread(b2);
    Thread t5 = new Thread(b2);
    Thread t6 = new Thread(b2);

    t1.setName("t1");
    t2.setName("t2");
    t3.setName("t3");
    t4.setName("t4");
    t5.setName("t5");
    t6.setName("t6");


    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

    t4.start();
    t5.start();
    t6.start();

}
```

}

**Question** :

1. What would be the effect of using `static` reference/object in `synchronized` block (as in **Example#3**)
2. What would be the effect of using **non-static** reference/object in `synchronized`  block.
3. Also does the Static reference `NUM` in synchronized block (`synchronized(NUM)`) is equivalent to `synchronized(Bar.class)` ?

Answer (score 2):

**What would be the effect of using static reference/object in synchronized block (as in Example#3)**

The static object is shared between the threads, and thus all threads that will block when one thread acquires the lock.
 Meaning if t1 is inside the synchronized block then t2, t3, ..., t6 are blocked.

**But** there is a trick in the code you provided. `NUM++` this will create a new NUM object since the Integer class is immutable. So what will happen, say t1 acquires the lock and enters the synchronized block. Now, t1 executes `NUM++`. Now many cases could happen.

1. If another thread was blocked before Num++ was executed this thread will remain block until t1 exits the sychronized block.
2. If a thread was not blocked (say t2) and Num++ was executed by t1, then t2 will not block since the Num is now a new Integer. Thus the lock is different 
   and t2 enters the block acquiring the lock for the new Integer.

And the same story can happen with all the threads. **In fact, it is possible to have all the threads in the synchronized block at the same time.**

**What would be the effect of using non-static reference/object in synchronized block.**

Assuming that non-static object is not shared between the instances of the class Bar, thus only one thread of t1,t2,t3 can be in the synchronized block. similarly for t4,t5,t6. However, if it is shared it has the same effect as a static object.

**Also does the Static reference NUM in synchronized block (synchronized(NUM)) is equivalent to synchronized(Bar.class) ?**

It is if you don't change NUM as I explained in the answer to the first question

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether the mutex is static or non-static, as long as it is the same object.

To answer your first question, the `NUM` object would be the same for all of your threads, therefore no two threads would be able to acquire a lock on it at the same time.

The second question is more tricky... if the object in the `synchronized` block is the same for all of your threads then they would perform like they did in the previous scenario. If each thread has it own object then there would be nothing preventing all of your thread from entering the critical section at a time.

Also, remember that there's a huge chance that when you call `t2.start()` t1 might already have finished processing (same might happen to your other threads) so make sure that you don't get fooled by what you see being printed on the console...

Comment: Would be best if you can describe ` therefore no two threads would be able to acquire a lock on it at the same time.` in terms of thread name t1,t2....t6.

Comment: If threads t1 to t5 try to acquire a lock on object o1 (`synchronized (o1)` {...}) but thread t6 is currently holding a lock on that same object then t1-t5 will block (ie. wait) until thread t2 releases the lock. At that point, some other thread will acquire it and enter the critical section.

Comment: Also please consider the 3rd question.

Comment: Yes. Just as there is one single instance of Bar.class in the system, there is a single instance of `NUM` too.

Answer (score 0):

Before going to your question You will need to understand the below points.

All the above synchronization will have different level of mutex in object or class level.

**What is Mutex**

In Java, every object has one and only one monitor and mutex associated with it. The single monitor has several doors into it, however, each indicated by the synchronized keyword. When a thread passes over the synchronized keyword, it effectively locks all the doors. Of course, if a thread doesn't pass across the synchronized keyword, it hasn't locked the door, and some other thread is free barge in at any time. Source : [Click here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076797/java-concurrency/programming-java-threads-in-the-real-world--part-2.html)

**Synchronization block with `this`/Synchronized Instance Method**

- Mutex will be applied on a current object.
- Mutext will be shared across all **instance method**.

```
      public class Test {    
            public synchronized void a() {
            }       
            public void b() {
                synchronized(this) {
                }
            }
         }
```

For Eg : Thread_1 & Thread_2 are call methods `a` and `b` respectively. So Either one of the thread will wait for others. Thread_3 calls method `a` or `b` it will wait as per earlier statement.

**Synchronization block with `.class`/Synchronized static Method**

- Mutex will be applied on the class object of that Class.
- Mutext will be shared across all **static method**.

```
      public class Test {    
            public static  synchronized void a() {
            }       
            public static void b() {
                synchronized(Test.class) {
                }
            }
         }
```

Thread_1 & Thread_2 are call methods `a` and `b` respectively. So Either one of the thread will wait for others. Thread_3 calls method `a` or `b` it will wait as per earlier statement.Across all object of that class and static reference have same mutex for those **static methods**.

Note : Synchronized instance method will have mutex on object level. So It will not affect above condition.

**Synchronization block with `instance reference/object`.**

- Mutex will apply on a user defined object in instance level.
- One mutex object will be used one or more instance method.

```
public class Test {
    Object obj1  = new Object();
    Object obj2  = new Object();
    public void a() {
        synchronized (obj1) {
        }
    }
    public void b() {
        synchronized(obj2) {
        }
    }
    public void c() {
        synchronized (obj1) {
        }
    }
}
```

If Thread_1 and Thread_2 call a and b respectively. Both will granted to do. If Thread_3 calls `c` or `a`. it will be waiting for Thread_1 completes. So we can define lock in each method in instance level.

**Synchronization block with `static reference/object`.**

- Mutex will apply on a user defined object in class level.
- One mutex object will be used one or more instance method.

public class Test {
    static Object obj1  = new Object();
    static Object obj2  = new Object();
    public void a() {
        synchronized (obj1) {
        }
    }
    public void b() {
        synchronized(obj2) {
        }
    }
    public void c() {
        synchronized (obj1) {
        }
    }
}

It will same just like instanse reference. But mutex will same across all instance of the class. 
So If thread_1 , thread_2 calls `a` method , only one thread_1 will acquire lock. other will wait.
Because its class level.